# Discord.js voice bot cuts out when playing local mp3 file

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, voice

My bot plays an mp3 sound however it cuts out near the end, especially with short (<2s) files.

Reinstalled ffmpeg many times

```
client.on('message', message => {
  // Voice only works in guilds, if the message does not come from a guild,
  // we ignore it
  if (!message.guild) return;

    if (message.content === '!sound') {
    // Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves
    if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
      message.member.voiceChannel.join()
        .then(connection => { // Connection is an instance of VoiceConnection
          const dispatcher = connection.playFile('C:/Users/X/Desktop/my-bot/Sounds/SJW2.mp3');

          dispatcher.on("end", end => {connection.disconnect});
        })
        .catch(console.log);
        client.on('end', () => {
  // The song has finished
});
```

No errors, sounds just cut out near the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using opus voice. Also, your hosting's internet speed affects it. It is likely due to high latency

Comment: Solved this - it was an issue with discord.js v10, upgrading to v12 fixed it